# What is the fastest way to return a SQL Server database to a point in time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

The business problem: we would like to run a series of automated tests, each against a database, starting in a known state.

Right now, the best way I know to guarantee that the database is in its original state at the start of a test is to restore the database from a `.bak` backup file prior to each test, but this is slow.

Is there a faster way?

We are using SQL Server 2016, and primarily .NET technology.

(Note: I know there are more database-centric forums, but since I am asking from a developer point of view it seems reasonable to start here.)

Comment: Have you considered running your scripts in a transaction and then rolling it back? Note that this doesn't have quite the same effect on `IDENTITY` columns as a restore (with point in time) will have, as the identity values will still be used.

Comment: You can make a [database snapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql) and revert to it. I seem to recall (but don't quote me on it since it's been quite a while since I've tested) that this can be faster than restoring a full backup, depending on what you're doing with it. From 2016 SP1 onwards, this is supported in all editions. This is still much slower than rolling back transactions, or properly mocking your database so your tests no longer rely on it (if they're not specifically testing database code, of course).

Comment: If the "original state" does not involve a lot of data, a clean sweep where you truncate all the tables and insert whatever data the tests need first can beat out all of these methods on speed. Also, deploying a DACPAC or BACPAC for the initial state (before running all tests) can be both faster and more convenient than restoring a backup (the latter of which is tied to a specific version of SQL Server and won't restore on earlier versions). As a bonus, you get to use database projects, which can have a positive effect on keeping your code maintainable.

Comment: How large is the starting point DB ? How much new information or changes to the DB schema will occur during each test ?  Have you considered running the tests against a copy of the DB ?

Comment: If you have the transaction logs, you could restore the first backup, and then run the transaction logs based on date.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, snapshotting looks like exactly what I am looking for, I just hadn't googled the right terms :) Thanks much!

Comment: Also, @JeroenMostert - I do mock out the DB when possible, but this case required significant changes to both the DB and processing code, so I am looking at an approach that will test both.

Comment: Hey, I'm not judging. In love, war and making existing things testable, everything is allowed. I've had some experience making things testable with a database included (that was before snapshotting was available in all editions, so it involved a bunch of `TRUNCATE TABLE`s and copying things from production into database projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Database snapshotting](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database-snapshot-transact-sql) appears to do exactly what I want with minimal overhead.

Create snapshot:

```
CREATE DATABASE t19314_ss ON
  ( NAME = TimeStar,
    FILENAME = 'C:\temp\snappy.ss' ) AS SNAPSHOT OF t19314
```

Revert to snapshot:

```
RESTORE DATABASE t19314 from DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 't19314_ss';
```